# How can I get the word after last slash in each line in a multiline cell using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of data in the multiline cell. I used this code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace What:="*/", Replacement:="", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

But it didn't work. I want the format in the below image:

[image: word after last slash in a multiline cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following code will do what you expect it to:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set you worksheet
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on column A

For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last
    ValueList = Split(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbLf) 'split next line values into array
    For x = LBound(ValueList) To UBound(ValueList) 'loop through array
        pos = InStrRev(ValueList(x), "/") 'get the position of the last /
        ValueList(x) = Right(ValueList(x), Len(ValueList(x)) - pos) 'remove everything before the last /
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & vbLf & ValueList(x) 'pass the newly created values into Column B
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The lines within a multiline cell are separated by CHAR(10)
You probably want to split based on that then for each line, you want the INSTRREV function - [see examples here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instrrev.php)